# How to use 2 SPI devices, LoRa and SD Card, on ESP32?

Tags: sd-card, spi, esp32, lora

Trying to code Heltec ESP32 LoRa with integrated OLED and with attached SD Card.

I've gotten both the SD Card (CS 21) and the LoRa (CS 18) to work individually, but when I try to get both working in the same program, I can't.

```
//
// Heltec 32 LoRa OLED (with SD Card)
//               ______________
//          Gnd |    |  USB|   | Gnd
//           5v |    | port|   |  5v
//          3v3 |    |_____|   | 3v3
//          Gnd |      ALL     |  36<-     <- : Input Only!
//           Rx |     GPIO     |  37<-
//           Tx |     3.3v     |  38<-
//          RST |   ________   |  39<-
//            0 |  |        |  |  34<-
//    (SCL)  22 |  |        |  |  35<-
// SPI MISO  19 |  |        |  |  32<-
//           23 |  |        |  |  33<-
//LoRa CS(HI)18 |  |        |  |  25  (LED)
// SPI SCK    5 |  |  OLED  |  |  26  LoRa IRQ
//OLED SCL   15 |  |        |  |  27  SPI MOSI
//            2 |  |        |  |  14  LoRa Rst
//OLED SCA    4 |  |        |  |  12
//           17 |  |________|  |  13
//OLED RST   16 |______________|  21  (SD_CS)
//

#include <mySD.h>        //  SD Card (VMA304)
#include "SSD1306.h"     //  OLED
#include <LoRa.h>        //  LoRa

File root;

//       OLED       Pin
#define  SDA          4   //  Serial Data
#define  SCL         15   //  Serial Clock
#define  oRST        16   //  Reset
#define  OLED_ADDR 0x3C   //  OLED display TWI address

SSD1306         display(OLED_ADDR, SDA, SCL);
//  OLED screen text rows:
#define  row1     0     //  y=0 is top row of size 1 text
#define  row2    10
#define  row3    20
#define  row4    30
#define  row5    40
#define  row6    50     //  row7 at 70 is too low

//  SPI port #2:  SD Card Adapter
#define  SD_CLK      5
#define  SD_MISO    19
#define  SD_MOSI    27
#define  SD_CS      21

//  SPI port:  LoRa (SX1278) 
//       LoRa      Pin
#define  LoRa_SCK    5
#define  LoRa_MISO  19
#define  LoRa_MOSI  27
#define  LoRa_CS    18
#define  LoRa_RST   14    //  LoRa_Reset
#define  DI0        26    //  LoRa_IRQ
#define  BAND    915E6    //  other freq: 433E6  // or ? LoRa f(MHz)

#define  Select    LOW   //  Low CS means that SPI device Selected
#define  DeSelect  HIGH  //  High CS means that SPI device Deselected

File     sessionFile;   //  SD card filenames are restricted to 8 characters + extension

int counter = 0;        //  count sent LoRa messages

/***********************************************************/
void setup(){  
  // set output pins
  pinMode(oRST,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SD_CS,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LoRa_CS,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LoRa_CS, DeSelect);

  // set GPIO16 Low then High to Reset OLED
  digitalWrite(oRST, LOW);  
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(oRST, HIGH);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);                     //  wait to connect to computer

  display.init();
  display.flipScreenVertically();
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_10);
  display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
  display.clear();
  display.display();

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  digitalWrite(SD_CS, Select);    //  SELECT (Low) SD Card SPI
  if (!SD.begin( SD_CS, SD_MOSI, SD_MISO, SD_CLK )) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    //  now what?
  } else {
    Serial.println("initialization done.");
    display.drawString( 5,row1,"SD Card OK!" );
    display.display();
    delay(1000);
  }
  /* open "test.txt" for writing */
  root = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (root) {
    root.println("Hello world!");
    root.flush();
    root.close();
  } else {    //  file open error
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
  display.drawString( 5,row2,"Wrote in test.txt" );
  display.display();
  delay(100);
  /* after writing, then reopen the file and read it */
  root = SD.open("test.txt");
  if (root) {    /* read from the file to the end of it */
    while (root.available()) {  // read the file
      Serial.write(root.read());
    }
    root.close();
  } else {
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
  display.drawString( 5,row3,"Read from test.txt" );
  display.display();
  delay(100);
  //  done testing the SD Card
  digitalWrite(SD_CS, DeSelect);    //  DESELECT (high) SD Card SPI
  SD.end();
  delay( 100 ); 

  //  now test the LoRa

  SPI.begin( LoRa_SCK, LoRa_MISO, LoRa_MOSI, LoRa_CS );

  LoRa.setPins( LoRa_CS, LoRa_RST, DI0 );
  digitalWrite(LoRa_CS, Select);   //  SELECT (low) LoRa SPI 
  Serial.println("LoRa Sender");
  if (!LoRa.begin(BAND)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    display.drawString( 5, row4, "LoRa Init Failed!");
    display.display();
    // now what?
  } else {
    Serial.println("LoRa Initial OK!");
    display.drawString( 5, row4, "LoRa Initialized OK!");
    display.display();
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("Setup done!");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  Serial.println(counter);
  display.clear();
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_16);
  display.drawString(3, 5, "Sending packet ");
  display.drawString(50, 30, String(counter));
  display.display();
  // send packets
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("Hi. Sent packet #");
  LoRa.print(counter);
  LoRa.endPacket();
  counter++;
  delay(500);
}
```

I have a LoRa receiver working to read the messages.  With the code posted above, the SD Card works.  And the LoRa says that it is transmitting messages, but the receiver doesn't see them, and it stops after 4 messages.

Comment: let the libraries handle the CS pins

Comment: @Juraj  - I like that.  But how?

Comment: you set the pins to both, they know what to do

Comment: I'm wondering if it has to do with the shared MISO line.  If I pull it off the SD Card, the LoRa works, but of course, the SD Card stops. https://www.pjrc.com/better-spi-bus-design-in-3-steps/   I tried the MISO volt divider with 1k's, but it didn't work.

Comment: what SD adapter do you use?

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Micro-SD-Storage-Board-Mciro-SD-TF-Card-Memory-Shield-Module-SPI-For-Arduino-/200958993125

Comment: do you power it from 5 V pin?

Comment: I do supply 5v from the ESP32 to the SD Card adapter, yes.

Comment: It's also possible to use two separate SPI ports for communicating with both the devices in parallel

Answer (score 1):

I got both the LoRa and SD Card to work - alternatively - by adding the right resistors.
The SD Card CS needs a 1k ohm to 3.3v.
The MISO pin 19 needs a 1k ohm to 3.3v, 
and a 1k ohm to GND,
and a 100 ohm to the SD Card MISO pin.

```
//OLED RST   16 |______________|  21  (SD_CS), w/1k ohm to 3.3v
//           RESISTORS ARE IMPORTANT
// SPI MISO needs 1k ohm to 3.3v, 1k ohm to GND, 100 ohm to SD MISO.
```

After setting things up, in the loop():

```
void loop() {
  //  use the LoRa
  SPI.begin( LoRa_SCK, LoRa_MISO, LoRa_MOSI, LoRa_CS );
  LoRa.setPins( LoRa_CS, LoRa_RST, DI0 );
  digitalWrite(SD_CS, DeSelect);    //  deselet SD Card SPI
  digitalWrite(LoRa_CS, Select);    //  SELECT (low) LoRa SPI 
  if( LoRa.begin(BAND)) {
```

LoRa activity.  Then ...

```
    SPI.end();
  }
  if (!SD.begin( SD_CS, SD_MOSI, SD_MISO, SD_CLK )) {
```

SD Card activity, ending the loop() with ...

```
    //  done using the SD Card
    digitalWrite(SD_CS, DeSelect);    //  DESELECT (high) SD Card SPI
    SD.end();
```

This probably isn't optimized, but it works!  Yay!

Comment: HI Rick, thanks a lot for this information. Do you have a Diagram for the resistors please

Answer (score 0):

if you use Heltec WIFI LoRa 32 (v2), it would be better to put the SD card SCK on 36,,39 pin. The 21 is used by Vext Control.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to control the chip select pin for each device, HIGH for
not active and LOW for active, and don't be active at the same time.